Fantasy book series about a brother and sister able to use more of their brain than the average human
I can't remember the title of a book series.
Here's what I know about it:

The main characters are a brother and a sister
They have special abilities (might involve telepathy) and are part of an organisation of people having said abilities. I think the abilities are hereditary
They have creatures from another realm helping them / assigned to them that are (I think?) polymorph and that age backwards (start very old and end as babies)
The series involves time travel somehow (and time loops), I remember distinctly 2 occurrences of time travel

Once some people travel in ancient Egypt and there's a weird story about a baby from ancient Egypt travelling to current times
A time travel involves the tale of Saint Michael and the dragon, and in this rewriting of the tale, on of the creatures from the other realm turns into a spear and is the spear that kills the dragon


The creature from the other realm are connected to some sort of egg made of a weird matter, which can be used to control people (communicate via telepathy and enforce will on others)

Chances are I read this book in French but it might not be originally in French

When did you read this?

At least 4 or 5 years ago
